# I want to make 2 drop menu & 1 slide bar at jupyter notebook

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, jupyter-notebook, sidebar, ipywidgets

I have a dataframe that contains the category of the item, item_id, the sales of all days and the total sales of each product(sum(axis=1)).

The next 4 dataframes have 2 columns item_id and sales depending on the category and their name is household_sort,hobbies_sort,foods_sort and sales_total that includes the total sales of each product.

I want to create 3 dependent widgets (2 drop menu and 1 slide bar) at jupyter notebook.First i want a drop menu about some categories of prducts  (for example sales of foods) which are defined in dictionary cat in the code below.After a slidebar where the user will specify the limits of  total sales from the category of th first drop menu.Finally drop menu with item id according to the previous
I tried this code but i cant change the values of the second drop menu.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, Dropdown
import ipywidgets as wg
range_slider=wg.IntRangeSlider(value=[1000,10000],min=sales_total['total'].min() - 5,max=sales_total['total'].max() + 5,description='Test:',readout_format='d')

cat={'HOBBIES_SALES':hobbies_sort[(hobbies_sort['total']>= range_slider.value[0]) & (hobbies_sort['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id'],
     'HOUSEHOLD_SALES':household_sort[(household_sort['total']>= range_slider.value[0]) & (household_sort['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id'],
     'FOODS_SALES':foods_sort[(foods_sort['total']>= range_slider.value[0]) & (foods_sort['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id'],
     'TOTAL_SALES':sales_total[(sales_total['total']>=range_slider.value[0]) & (sales_total['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id']}
catW=Dropdown(options=cat.keys())
idW=Dropdown(options=cat[catW.value])

    
display(catW,range_slider,idW)
```

Comment: The problem is that the second drop menu dont get the item id that met the criteria. how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Both dropdowns aren't essentially linked. Since you are populating the values on the server side you may link both widgets using `observe` and an event handler of choice.

### Solution

Add an event handler ([reference](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html)) as follows which updates the options available in the second dropdown based on the selected category in the first. You can add as many events as desired and perform any computations in the handler. This was tested in Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook v5.7.3

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, Dropdown
import ipywidgets as wg
range_slider=wg.IntRangeSlider(value=[1000,10000],min=sales_total['total'].min() - 5,max=sales_total['total'].max() + 5,description='Test:',readout_format='d')

cat={'HOBBIES_SALES':lambda : hobbies_sort[(hobbies_sort['total']>= range_slider.value[0]) & (hobbies_sort['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id'],
     'HOUSEHOLD_SALES':lambda : household_sort[(household_sort['total']>= range_slider.value[0]) & (household_sort['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id'],
     'FOODS_SALES':lambda : foods_sort[(foods_sort['total']>= range_slider.value[0]) & (foods_sort['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id'],
     'TOTAL_SALES':lambda : sales_total[(sales_total['total']>=range_slider.value[0]) & (sales_total['total']<=range_slider.value[1])]['item_id']}
catW=Dropdown(options=cat.keys())
idW=Dropdown(options=cat[catW.value]())

# Creating event handler
def ddl_event_handler(event):
    idW.options=cat[event['new']]() #updating the options to the selected value

# Add an observer
catW.observe(ddl_event_handler,names="value")
#optionally specify a `display_id` to update the same area
display(catW,range_slider,idW,display_id="options_area")
```

### Reference and Resources

Linking Widgets - https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html

Comment: i want to take the values of the range_slider and based on this set the limits for sales and from there to show the item id at the second drop menu who takes the values of the dictionary

Comment: @Spyros I've updated the solution to facilitate easy recalculation of category values based on slider and first dropdown. Each Category value is now a lambda function that is called to retrieve the values based on the first dropdown and range slider

Comment: all correctly thanks a lot but 
why when I run it in Edit it runs normally while when I do save and commit and I see the notebook the 2nd drop down does not change. Did you know the reason ?
https://www.kaggle.com/spyrospetsis/prospatheia-gia-to-wow this is the link and your code is at the end of the notebook

Comment: The saved and committed notebook is a static file, actually json, storing static code and results from a previous run from each cell. Your python code requires a running python environment in order to process the events and execute the python backend code that you've used to determine the set of possible options for the second dropdown.